# Reading .ini File When Converted into Runnable Jar File

Tags: java, bufferedreader, filereader, ini, ini4j

I have a project which I am going to convert it into runnable jar file. I am storing some of the configurations in my ini file with using `ini4j`.

It works when I simply set the directory `getConf = new Ini(new FileReader(path));`, but it wont work when I use `getResourceAsStream()`

```
public class IniReader {

// When I set it like that, it works..
private static String path = "../conf.ini";

public static String readIni(String val, String getOb, String fetchOb) {
    Ini getConf = null;

    try {
    // When I set it like that, it works..
        getConf = new Ini(new FileReader(path));

        // I want to use this version but I am getting null error.
        //getConf = new Ini(new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getResourceAsStream("conf.ini"))));

    } catch (InvalidFileFormatException e) {
        System.err.print("Error InvalidFileFormat : " + e.getMessage() + "\n");
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.err.print("Error FileNotFoundException : " + e.getMessage() + "\n");
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.err.print("Error IOException : " + e.getMessage() + "\n");
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return val = getConf.get(getOb).fetch(fetchOb);
}
```

When I try to read my iniFile I am getting the error below;

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.io.Reader.<init>(Reader.java:78)
    at java.io.InputStreamReader.<init>(InputStreamReader.java:113)
    at org.ini4j.Ini.load(Ini.java:104)
    at org.ini4j.Ini.<init>(Ini.java:56)
    at com.test.ttf.IniReader.readIni(IniReader.java:28)
    at com.test.ttf.SlashSCR.InitProg(SlashSCR.java:116)
    at com.test.ttf.InitProg.main(InitProg.java:18)
```

This is where I want to read .ini file

[image]

**EDIT**

I also tried the following;

```
    Ini getConf= new Ini();
    getConf.load(Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader().getClass().getResourceAsStream("../conf.ini"));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you want to load the config from the jar, you can use the path `getResource()` and `getResourceAsStream()` functions. 
The `NullPointerException` indicates (most likely, because it is always hard to tell with many statements on one line) that the resource was not found (which silently returns `null`)

If you want to load it from a local file, then you just do it the original method (with the `FileReader`) . However you have to set the path relative to the execution directory (where you run `java` from). This most likely is the same directory as your jar. In that case you should use `"conf.ini"` instead of `"../conf.ini"`

Comment: Thanks! I am going to make .exe and .app version of this file, should I put my .ini file in resources directory and generate shortcut next to exe and app file or should I directly let user access ini file via original file which is in same directory?

Comment: This doesn't matter, as long as they are on the same relative location compared to the run location. When you use a shortcut, setting the run directory is a property of the shortcut (so this might make it a bit more complicated).